# Get Y value in line chart using cubic lines

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the Charts library in an iOS application. The required chart I am implementing, displays realtime values fed from a hardware peripheral. I already implemented adding new entries and scrolling to the latest value, so the chart appears to be updating constantly (sort of flowing to the left from the right side of the screen).

Now I need to draw a circle on the right side of the graph, but for that I would need to receive the Y value for the currently visible X. This is easy to get for the points in the DataSet, but I can't find a way to get Y value for the interpolated points between the DataSet values.

Here is what the graph looks like:
[image]

Comment: Would it be acceptable for you to calculate the cubic interpolation yourself?